# Books with multiple storylines

Tags: story-identification, books, choose-your-own-adventure

Early in my childhood library, I chanced upon some books where at the end of the chapter it had multiple options to chose how one wants the story to proceed indicating page numbers. I don't remember if it was there at end of every chapter. I think it was a sci-fi book. Can somenone help me with such book/series?

Comment: A choose your own adventure book.

Comment: [Choose your own Goosebumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Give_Yourself_Goosebumps)

Comment: What was the storyline like? There are thousands of "choose your own adventure" or "decide your destiny" style books

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific, what were some of the stories? Were they all linked? What did the cover(s) look like? Was there any part of them that you remember?

Comment: Do you remember what would happen if you chose a 'wrong' ending? Was there 'dead ends', etc?

Comment: I voted to close this because it is too broad. Please [edit] in more details and we may be able to help. You've described a whole genre of books including Dungeon & Dragons Endless Quest, Choose Your Own Adventure, Give Yourself Goosebumps, Lone Wolf and more. So many more.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I wasn't looking for one specific book but those types books and am glad for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

I think most popular multiple-ending book series was the "Choose Your Own Adventure" series. I know one science fiction related book in the series was "Inside UFO 54-40 (Choose Your Own Adventure #12).  There were two other popular series called "Fighting Fantasy" and "TwistAPlot". All three book series were for younger readers.